# Getting only True values and their respective indices from a Pandas series

Tags: pandas, boolean, series

I have a pandas series that looks like this, extracted on querying a dataframe.

```
t_loc=
312 False
231 True
324 True
286 False
123 False
340 True
```

I want only the indices that have 'True' boolean value.

I tried t_loc.index gives me all the indices. t_loc['True'] or t_loc[True] are both futile. Need help. 
Also, I need to update these locations with a single number if True. How can I update a column in a dataframe given the location numbers ?

Desired O/P:
[231,324,340]

Need to update eg. df[col1] @ 231.. is it df[col1].loc[231] ? How to specify multiple locations? Can we pass the entire list since I need to update it with only one value for all the locations ?

Comment: `t_loc.index[t_loc]`

Comment: Great !! Worked.. Thanks.. For the column update can I use   df['col1'].loc[a] = 40 (The value I want to update) given a= t_loc.index[t_loc]

Comment: Everything worked.. !!

Comment: Actually, you can simply do `df.loc[t_loc, 'col1'] = 40`.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works too :

```
t_loc.index[t_loc == True/False]
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try this as well

```
t_loc.astype(int).index[t_loc == 1]
```